# Como deixar um valor que vem do SQLite num EditText?

Tags: android-studio, sqlite

estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo no Android Studio, e tenho uma activity sobre uma carteirinha, e queria pegar a coluna ID do SQLite e deixar como valor padrão, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Marcos. Veja se isso ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37063222/8133067. Se não ajudar, posta um trecho do código que você já tem para termos uma ideia melhor do problema, sugiro que leia esse artigo da ajuda do site: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: agradeço pelas boas vindas, eu consegui resolver isso do ID, muito obg, só que deu um outro erro que não consigo resolver, vou abrir outra discussão para tentar resolver